# how to get Id of the button in listview?

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-listview

In my application  I am using a List Activity in which I have passed an ArrayAdapter the getView() method is like this

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mPosition= position;
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelistlayout, null, true);
    deleteButton= (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete_bn);
    deleteButton.setTag(position);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(names[position]);


    return rowView;

}
```

now I want to set onclicklistener() on the deleteButton. it shuould delete the item when corrosponding delete button is clicked. Please help me.

Comment: Check this link: [Handling Button clicks in a ListView Row](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html)

Comment: thanks Herry it is useful for me.

Comment: thanks Paresh Mayani the link is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
deleteButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick( View v ) {
  //Handle deleting the item here.
  // or item enable -> false
 v.getParent()
}
});
...
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use setTag method available for the view. Set the id/ position on deletebutton setTag and onClicklistener you can get the id/position by view.getTag()

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `OnClickListener` directly to the button inside `getView()`.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  mPosition= position;
  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelistlayout, null, true);
  deleteButton= (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete_bn);
  deleteButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View v ) {
      //Handle deleting the item here.
      //If you need the layout holding the button, you can probably get it by using v.getParent()
    }
  });
  TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
  textView.setText(names[position]);

  return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a snipped of code i recently used in my application

```
((Button) l.findViewById(R.id.btn_rm)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) { 

    list_of_elements.remove(position);      
    My_Custom_List_Adapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}                   
});
```

please note that this has been developed within an expandablelistadapter, so it may differ slightly from a regular listadapter

Answer (score 0):

1 .create interface with method delete(int position) .

2 .implement it in activity where you are using ListView

```
delete(int position) 
{
adapter.remove(position) // modify the syntax as per need .
}
```

3 .pass this interface to adapter through constructor .

4 .write onClickListener inside getView for deletebutton and call i`nterface.delete(position)`